# Can I host a Facebook Chatbot on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, firebase, chatbot

I created a chatbot to work with my fanpage on Facebook. This was done with a node.js base. When I do a 'firebase init', I get a /public folder and lots of other stuff. I do 'firebase deploy', but my bot is never called. Is there a way for work this out?

I have this as a reference:
[Hosting nodeJS app with firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622187/hosting-nodejs-app-with-firebase)
Still I got some faith this is a different case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What codebase are you working out of?

Comment: Well, I start my code with this:

'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request  = require('request');
const firebase = require('firebase');

I believe that is an appropriate answer to you inquiry, right?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I believe I got the answer now. Firebase only supports hosting for frontend stuff. For a chatbot I'd use something like NodeJS, PHP or other backend tecnologies. Thus, Heroku is a good call.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to Cloud Functions for Firebase to write a chat bot - I believe you might need to use a paid plan because the free tier does not allow Functions to make outbound calls.

I found a gist that appears to be an actual Facebook chat bot using functions:
https://gist.github.com/mikkipastel/37fa011e3aea7ebb9941fb3dab6f1186